# React does not update state through its function setState when is called with event.target

Tags: arrays, react-hooks

Given this code, I want to update selectedOption value by selecting an option.
on Change it will return correct value as event.target, but not in useState.

```
let options = [
  {
    value: "",
    label: "All",
  },
  {
    value: "0",
    label: "With Producers",
  },
  {
    value: "1",
    label: "In our warehouse",
  },
];

<Form.Control
  as="select"
  onChange={(e) => {
    console.log("e.target.value ==> in select", e.target.value);
    setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
    handleSubmit(e);
  }}
  className="form-select"
>
  {options.map((option) => {
    return (
      <option key={option.value} value={option.label}> {option.label} </option>
    );
  })}
</Form.Control>


const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    
    console.log('e.target.value', e.target.value)
    
    setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
    
    const data = dataAuction;
    let filteredArray = [];

    if ( selectedOption == 'With Producers' ) {
      filteredArray = data.filter(item => {
        // console.log('condition', item.is_resell == '1' && item.is_no_deposit == '1' || item.is_resell == '0')
        console.log('is_resell', item.auction.is_resell)
        // return item.auction.is_resell == selectedOption;
        return item.auction.is_resell == 1 && item.auction.is_no_deposit == 1
      });
      // setFilteredData(filteredArray);
      // setDataAuction(filteredArray)
      console.log('if 1');
    } else if ( selectedOption == 'In our warehouse' ) {
      filteredArray = data.filter(item => {
        // console.log('condition', item.is_resell == '1' && item.is_no_deposit == '1' || item.is_resell == '0')
        console.log('is_resell', item.auction.is_resell)
        // return item.auction.is_resell == selectedOption;
        return item.auction.is_resell == 1 && item.auction.is_no_deposit == 0
      });
      // setFilteredData(filteredArray);
      // setDataAuction(filteredArray)
      console.log('else if 1');
      
    } else if ( selectedOption == 'All' ) {
      console.log('else');
      filteredArray = data.map(item => {
        // console.log('condition', item.is_resell == '1' && item.is_no_deposit == '1' || item.is_resell == '0')
        console.log('else if 2')
        // return item.auction.is_resell == selectedOption;
        return item
      });
      // setDataAuction(filteredArray)
    }
    setFilteredData(filteredArray);
    setDataAuction(filteredArray)
    console.log('selectedOption =====>', selectedOption)
  };
```

I expect to update selectedOption state. but instead if i click of select, the event.target is correct but it iterates over 'options' array, not in sync with the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Hi React states are asynchronous that means once you update the value using setState the state won't get updated immediately

Instead of relying upon state you can try like this

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setSelectedOption(value);
    const data = dataAuction;
    let filteredArray = [];

    if ( value == 'With Producers' ) {
      filteredArray = data.filter(item => {
        return item.auction.is_resell == 1 && item.auction.is_no_deposit == 1
      });
    } else if ( value == 'In our warehouse' ) {
      filteredArray = data.filter(item => 
        return item.auction.is_resell == 1 && item.auction.is_no_deposit == 0
      });
    } else if ( value == 'All' ) {
      filteredArray = data.map(item => {
        return item
      });
    }
    setFilteredData(filteredArray);
    setDataAuction(filteredArray)
  };
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried like this. and it's the same story. State will not be updated on first click.